# how to change the value of a boolean method in main?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

Probably a pretty basic question:

But how can I change the value of a `boolean` method in main?

*example:*

```
class question{
  public boolean abc(){
    return false;
  }  
}
```

How do I go about making this method return true in my main class\or whatever? :D

Comment: `!abc()`? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: question is unclear, why do you want to change the boolean value in the main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main you can use `!` NOT to change to  `true`.

Say you called method from main,

```
boolean result = ! obj.abc();//Note it will change false to true and vice versa.
```